# sql conditional sum statement

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements, case

The sql conditional sum statement below keeps throwing me an error and I'm not sure why.
The logic should create a flag when any of the underlying flags are 1, thus the sum >=1.

```
Error message: mismatched nput '(' expecting <EOF>
```

```
,case when (sum(case when (TAB_flag = 1) OR
(TOP_SPOT_flag = 1) OR
(PAGE_flag = 1) OR
(DOWNLOAD_flag = 1) >= 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS any_p_flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two case expressions.  You need to enter `then/else` to your inner case expression.  You may not need an inner case expression and just sum your fields, I can't tell without a sample of the data.  The below should work:

```
,case when (sum(
  case when (TAB_flag = 1) OR
  (TOP_SPOT_flag = 1) OR
  (PAGE_flag = 1) OR
  (DOWNLOAD_flag = 1) then 1 else 0 end 
>= 1)
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS any_p_flag
```

If your flag fields contain `1` or `0` and you are looking for any `1` you could do this:

```
,case when 
sum(TAB_flag + TOP_SPOT_flag + PAGE_flag + DOWNLOAD_flag)  > 0
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS any_p_flag
```

Comment: Case _expressions_.

Comment: @EoinS,  I ran your recommendation but throws an error since I'm dealing with boolean not numeric. The underlying fields  ```tab_flag ``` is already a boolean

Comment: @jgtrz Please tag your question with correct DBMS - my favourite sql flavour doesn't include boolean types for example.

Comment: @jgtrz the rest of the values or integer?

Comment: @EoinS, your recommendation for flag fields, works. thank you for the explanations!